# Unable to specify type="response" in Caret's predict function

Tags: r, r-caret, roc, glmnet

I am trying to plot a ROC curve for my `glmnet` regression model. In order to do that, I am trying to predict using type = "response" in predict function:

```
 pred_glmnet_s10_2class <- predict(model_train_glmnet_s10_2class,
                                   newdata=testing_s10_2class,
                                   s = "model_train_glmnet_s10_2class$finalModel$lambdaOpt",
                                   type="response")
```

and I get the following error:

> Error in predict.train(model_train_glmnet_s10_2class, newdata =  testing_s10_2class,  : 
>        type must be either "raw" or "prob"

My predictions and class labels are binary 0 and 1 and have been factored. Any help is really appreciated. Also, any ideas on how to plot AUC (Area Under ROC curve) vs number of features? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: For your follow up questions on AUC, what have you tried ?

Comment: `predict` is generic. You need to know the class of `model_train_glmnet_s10_2class`. Then you can determine which of the many `predict` functions you are actually using. It's possible that there is no `type="response"` to that class of object.

Comment: The error message says it all! `Type` needs to be either `raw`or `prob`. `raw` is the default and returns the classification response (1 or 0). prob returns the probabilities.

Comment: @42- the error message answers the question: `predict.train`.

Comment: From the error message it would appear that "response" is not valid string for the type parameter.  Indeed this is confirmed from the Caret [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf) on CRAN.

Comment: @Calimo; yes, I know. It's an enduring puzzle to my why people don't read error messages or help pages.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `model_train_glmnet_s10_2class` was generated by `train` (showing the code would be helpful)...

Using `predict(model_train_glmnet_s10_2class)` is using `predict.train` and uses the optimal lambda values determined by `train` automatically. If you want the probabilities, just use `type = "prob"`.

Your syntax is consistent with `predict.glmnet` and not `predict.train`.

As said in the documentation, it is a really bad idea to use `model_train_glmnet_s10_2class$finalModel` directly to do the predictions